# Convergence of the 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

Here is my problem, I have two empirical distribution functions $F_n(x)$ and $G_n(x)$ constructed from two data sets with $n$ points each and I estimate their 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov (2-KS) statistic as $D_n \equiv \sup_x \{F_n(x) - G_n(x) \}$.

By the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, the sequence $D_n$ converges uniformly to a value $D_{\infty}$ almost surely. If $F_n$ and $G_n$ are realisations of the same underlying distribution, then $D_{\infty} = 0$ otherwise we have $D_{\infty} > 0$.

My problem is to know whether I can say anything about $D_{\infty}$ if I know only the values of $D_n$ for $n \in I = [1,n_{max}]$...because in practice I cannot generate infinite amount of data.

In particular, I had the (possibly wrong) "feeling" that if $D_n \leq a$ for almost all $n \in I$ and if $D_n$ has a decreasing trend on $I$, then I could say that $D_{\infty} \leq a$ in some sense or with some confidence.

I have no problem if this is only true with some probability but I do not know how to formulate such a statement rigorously, if it has any chance of holding at all of course.